# Installed Pandas but Python still can't find module

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried installing Pandas in many different ways. Currently, it is installed using Anaconda and I have created a virtual environment. Below it shows that Pandas is installed, yet the module still can't be detected. Sorry if this has been answered before. I am still a beginner with Python.

[Picture of current Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Vpa.png)

Comment: did you also install `ipython` with `conda`? Exit `ipython` and enter `python -c "import pandas"`, do you still get an import error?

Comment: That python interpreter session doesn't look like it should if you were using the anaconda one. Do you have another Python installed on your computer? Note, your list of installed packages from `conda` does not include `ipython`, yet, you are in an `ipython` shell. Also, I would suggest *not* using 32bit version of Python, which will limit you to less than 4 gigs of address space...

Comment: When I did the command above, I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rakat\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pa
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Comment: @rkat: seems like you have installed some packages with msi installers. Did you install `numpy` with `conda`? Try installing `numpy` with `conda` by entering `conda install -f numpy` and then `conda install -f pandas` (for the sake of completeness) in your terminal.

Comment: From the error log, it seems you need to install `numpy` first as `pandas` requires it. Please install that one first as advised then rerun the command again

Comment: @rkat: Oh, and I also see that you're executing python from `numpy-1.11.2`. If there's some code in there, it could mess up the installed `numpy-1.13.1` version when running python. Leave the directory by e.g. going two levels up: `cd ..\..`,then repeat the import test: `python -c "import pandas"`

Answer (score 0):

maybe it doesn't match with the version you use which version you use?You can find it by pressing python in a terminal.Maybe you dont find it in the version you are using!